# C# Asp.net Parsing JSon

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I had below Json string returned from API. How can I parse the string to object in C# asp.net. Any suggestion or reply are highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
[
[
    {
        "StatusCode": "24",
        "UndelCode": "",
        "UndelReason": "",
        "Status": "Order Placed",
        "WayBillNumber": "BX00011",
        "LastModifiedOn": "16/03/2022 12:03:44",
        "LastModifiedDate": "16/03/2022",
        "LastModifiedTime": "12:03:44",
        "TransitLocation": "XB3113",
        "NextLocation": "",
        "Description": "Order Placed"
    }
]
```

]

Comment: Create a class to represent the inner object, deserialize to `List<List<thatClass>>`.

Comment: Use below loop to get the details
var respList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<ClassModel>>>(responseJSon);
            foreach (var resp in respList)
            {
                foreach (var data in resp)
                {
                    data.Code
                }
            }